# SSH and remote X appication... not correct resolution..how to solve it?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, xorg, x-server

I'm running through a SSH connection with -X option, a remote graphic application but when it's launched I can't see correctly the whole screen due to a bad resolution parameter... how can I change that? Should I modify something on my localhost or on the remote server? If you have some approach on how X server works, that would be awesome.

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `ssh -X`, then the application is diplayed on your own screen with your own resolution. To see this, try

```
 export DISPLAY=localhost:10
 xrandr -q
```

on the (remote) server; the reply will be the properties of the X monitor on the (local) client. You can change the resolution with the usual `xrandr` command,

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1024
```

or whatever applies to you.

If you are annoyed by having to change the resolution of your work session, you can create a second, distinct and separate session, as follows: install `Xephyr` (the how depends on your distro, the package is called `xserver-xephyr` on Debian and derivatives), then on the local machine

```
 Xephyr -ac -br -noreset -resizeable -screen 800x600 :1 &
 DISPLAY=:1.0 ssh -Y me@remote.host
```

and then, on the remote server, you issue the command

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:10
```

then run your graphical application, it will appear on a separate window on your local pc.

Comment: whenever I run "xrandr -q" on the server I get " Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display "localhost:14.0" "  Also I'm not able to install anything on the server machine... damn!

Comment: @user1219766 This is a strange problem: that means you have a defective X11 configuration on the client. You will have to produce much more info about your configuration than you gave us so far.

Comment: On client side (local computer) I got a lot of info, but not running that on the server side.

Comment: @user1219766 Sorry for being so late in replying, I completely forgot about this: the issue most likely is that your remote server is **not** running an X11 server, i.e. it is a text-only server. If the command *ps ax | grep -i x11* returns nothing, then this is your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, was solved long time ago :)